# Is there a way to atomically batch produce in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a source from where I get a batch of messages. These messages need to be added to Kafka - reliably - no misses and no out of order.

If I use aync producer, when I put many messages, I wonder if a partition is down for some time, it would just skip that message and put the next message - this would result in a out of order message.

Is there a way, I can tell Kafka - to batch produce a set of messages and either atomically pass everything of fail everything ?

*I don't want to do a sync produce, as it would severely impact the throughput.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the message key for this.
Kafka guarantees the order of messages in a single partition, but not across multiple partitions. All messages with a single key are passed to a single partition - so their order is preserved. Also when sent as a batch, they shall all pass or fail together.
But there is a trade of: all these messages are handled by a single machine - no parallelism.

More background info on keys and partitions in the official kafka documentation here:
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_producers
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers

Comment: Hey, though I understand the ordering part, it is still not clear to me - how it could be sent as an atomic batch to kafka - could you point to me to the batch APIs/ docs that state this?

Comment: @GuruprasadGV: It depends on the implementation of your producer. Generally producers accumulate messages until they reach a certain number (min_messages) or certain time (linger_time) - then them as a batch. By setting these very high, you can effectively tell the producer to accumulate everything, and then send it manually via a flush method (or similar) once you are ready.